# Empty console after console.log() call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, console

So, my code is

```
$.getJSON("https://api.forecast.io/forecast/API_KEY/55.9931803,92.773715", function(data){
  console.log(data);
})
```

but console is empty. No errors, just nothing. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `data`'s empty probably

Comment: no, it's not. url works finely when you just put it in browser

Comment: Did you miss the message: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.forecast.io/forecast/099d7717a79a457e72fd4b3e6e54c89c/55.9931803,92.773715?_=1473625797525. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Try placing a `console.log('test')` to see if the code is actually executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't work the way that you're expecting it to (unless you're running that javascript from a frontend view that is hosted at forecast.io).

You are running into the classic Cross Domain resource issue.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Looks like they don't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

You'll probably need to curl the request on your web server (server-side) and issue your javascript request to your own web server.

Comment: Or use JSONP: [Forecast.io API Usage with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132790/forecast-io-api-usage-with-jquery)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Will try to do something with it